# Node WPAPI media cannot upload "rest_upload_no_data"

Tags: javascript, image

I got a problem in node WPAPI. It won't upload a photo.

It can create the post, but it cannot upload the image (internal , uri and file:// path ), none of these work.

The one giving me problems is the custom image field, with image, and description in a repeatable type.

The error message is "rest_upload_no_data". Why it cannot receive the data?

```
 await wp.setHeaders({ Authentication: `Bearer ${token}` });
  // Selection
  await wp
    .createMission()
    .create({
      title: 'testing11111',
      status: 'publish',
    })
    .then(async (post) => {
      console.log('come to result');
      console.log(post);
      const filePath = '../images/note.png';
      return wp
        .media()
        .file(filePath)
        .create({
          title: 'Amazing featured image',
          post: post.id,
        })
        .then((media) => {
          console.log(`Media uploaded with ID #${media.id}`);
        });
    })
    .catch(async (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      const error = err.message;
      throw error;
    });
});
```